# Splitting line-layer with point-layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, splitting, network

I have a separate layer with polylines that are merged into one object. I want to split it by a separate layers with points in QGIS.
 
I have tried using the SAGA tool "Split Lines at Point" and I have tried converting the points to lines and used the tool "Split with lines" as suggested in other threads. 
But I can't get the right result (as shown below) - the tools also splits the merged polyline in intersections and not just at the points.

**Before splitting the merged polyline object (I only want it to be split at the points):**
[image]

**After splitting the polyline object (I dont want it to split the lines marked in the red circle, but the tool also splits at these intersections):**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for you but its not exactly straighforward

1. Dissolve all lines if they aren't all dissolved [image]
2. Convert dissolved lines to single parts [image]
3. Create all line intersections [image]
4. Extract points which aren't in your starting points [image]
5. Extract lines intersecting the extracted points [image]
6. Extract the lines which will not be dissolved [image]
7. Run the "disconnected islands" plugin on the lines supposed to be dissolved (result of step 5) [image]
8. Dissolve the lines using the generated field attribute in step 7 [image] [image]
9. Merge the results of step 8 and 6 [image]

Final Result:
[image]