# Merge lines that lie between two points in QGIS

Tags: qgis

In QGIS I have a vector layer with multiple linestrings and a vector layer with multiple points.
I want to merge all lines that lie "in a row" between two points, so it becomes only one line between two points.

I don't want to merge all lines in the layer that intersect each other, only the ones that are in a row between two points.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting line-layer with point-layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429366/splitting-line-layer-with-point-layer-in-qgis)

Comment: The link above isn't exactly what you are trying to achievement but it will point you in the right direction

Comment: Do you want to use code or just the QGIS processing tools?

Answer (score 0):

Add an azimuth field to your lines. Use the following expression in the field calculator (I assume a line in your input has exactly 2 vertices!):

`degrees(azimuth(  point_n( @geometry , 1), point_n( @geometry, 2)))`

(you can skip the degrees call, but I hate radians ;-) ).

The azimuth field now contains the azimuth of each line (4 lines total) in degrees:

[image: original data with azimuth values calculated]

Then dissolve on the azimuth field, and check "keep disjoint geometries separate" (don't know the exact wording, I have a german QGIS).

[image: dissolve options]

The result contains 3 lines, the 90 degree lines are merged into one and the up-and-down-lines after it are not.

[image: result of dissolve]